# Old or older people

Tags: differences, adjectives, comparatives

Which is grammatically correct?

> *Old* people are often lonely.

Or

> *Older* people are often lonely.

I understand context matters. I just want to know when it is right to use one or the other.

Comment: It depends on the context.

Comment: @whythagoras - Please elaborate.

Comment: In what context (piece of text) you want to use it? Can you add that to the question?

Comment: How about using 'Elderly' instead?

Comment: Both are _gramatically_ correct. But they mean subtly different things.

Comment: As others have said, please clarify.  Note  that "Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase **older people** is a euphemism for **old people**.